# GHC claims module only available as a boot module when it shouldn't be

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have this dependency graph (ignoring dependencies on third-party modules):

```
Main:
    GSI.Util
    GSI.Value
    GSI.Result
    GSI.Eval
    GSI.ByteCode
    GSI.Thread
GSI.Main:
    GSI.Value
    GSI.ByteCode
GSI.Thread:
    GSI.Util
    GSI.RTS
    GSI.Value
    GSI.Result
    GSI.Eval
GSI.Eval:
    GSI.Util
    GSI.RTS
    GSI.Value
    GSI.Result
    ACE
GSI.Eval (.hs-boot):
    GSI.Value
ACE:
    GSI.RTS
    GSI.Value
    GSI.ByteCode
    GSI.Result
    {-# SOURCE #-} GSI.Eval
GSI.ByteCode:
    GSI.Util
    GSI.Value
    {-# SOURCE #-} GSI.Thread
GSI.ByteCode (.hs-boot):
    {-# SOURCE #-} GSI.Value
    {-# SOURCE #-} GSI.Thread
GSI.Result:
    GSI.Util
    GSI.RTS
    GSI.Value
GSI.Value:
    GSI.Util
    GSI.RTS
    {-# SOURCE #-} GSI.ByteCode
```

(I'd like to cut that graph down further, but I honestly am lost as to which pieces are relevant.  .hs-boot files not listed have no dependencies on my code).  When I do

```
ghc --make Main.hs
```

I get this message:

```
[10 of 13] Compiling ACE              ( ACE.hs, ACE.o ) [GSI.ByteCode changed]
module GSI.Thread cannot be linked; it is only available as a boot module
```

What on earth?  I'm importing GSI.Thread not as a boot module from Main, so how can GHC claim it's only available as a boot module?  (And, for that matter, why can't GHC just detect this situation and include the non-boot module automatically?)

Comment: Well `ACE` is not `Main` and `ACE` (but not `Main`) is involved in an import cycle with `GSI.Thread`, so this message hardly seems unreasonable. You have some Template Haskell or something in `ACE`?

Comment: @ReidBarton - I don't understand at all.  You seem to know what this error message means - and Google doesn't - so maybe you could explain that?  I'm completely lost.

Comment: I don't really know what it means except that it comes from the ghci linker, so you must be using Template Haskell or something like it.

Comment: Right. The problem is that ACE uses Template Haskell from GSI.Value (everything does, it's necessary for error reporting) but GSI.Value depends (inessentially, just needs types) on GSI.ByteCode, which depends (inessentially, just needs types) on GSI.Thread. Hmm

Comment: I don't know exactly how TH dependency tracking works, but considering `GSI.Thread` imports `ACE` via normal imports (through `GSI.Eval`), its code surely can't be available when running splices in `ACE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was that ACE and GSI.Value had a circular dependency:

```
ACE -> GSI.Value -> GSI.Thread -> GSI.Eval -> ACE
```

This is an irresolvable problem because ACE uses a function from GSI.Value in a Template Haskell splice.  That requires GHC to dynamically load GSI.Value in order to compile ACE; but that is clearly impossible.

The solution was to move the Thread type out of GSI.Thread, and to a separate module that could avoid any dependency on GSI.Eval or GSI.Value.